# Java NetBeans - No detecta llamado de la clase

Tags: java

Estoy creando un proyecto en Java usando netbeans, cree un JFrame en un Class aparte del Main que se encuentra en otra clase, al hacer el llamado del Frame en en main me detecta como si no hubiese declarado el frame.

[image: imagen]

arriba cree el objeto que llama a la clase y no me mandó error, pero al momento de llamarlo desde el Main me sale que la variable "inicio" no existe

Comment: `inicio` es una **propiedad** de `Hexagon`, NO es un método, por tanto, los paréntesis `()` en `me.inicio()` están totalmente fuera de lugar.

Comment: ¿Quieres crear una instancia de la misma clase en la que ya estás? No lo entiendo...

Comment: En la otra clase tengo la clase HexagonInicio  que es un jframe (implements jframe) y desde el Main que está en otra clase trato es de inicializar el frame